# Out of memory: Killed process

Tags: ram, swap, cuda, gpu, memory-usage

I got from `dmesg`

```
Out of memory: Killed process 24502 (python) total-vm:19568804kB, anon-rss:14542148kB, file-rss:4kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:1000 pgtables:31232kB oom_score_adj:0
```

How can I increase the size of the memory instead of buying a new ram?

I have (`free`):

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           15G        1.8G         13G        202M        711M         13G
Swap:          4.0G        1.6G        2.4G
```

I have a laptop with RTX 2060 Ram 16 GB, how can I use it for this problem?

Comment: You have to check on sites like [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) or [codereview.stackexchange.com](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) how to rewrite your script to run with the available RAM.

Answer (score 3):

Your output shows that Python consumed 14.5G of memory (all of your RAM, and deep into your Swap) before the kernel killed it to protect you.

Most likely, there is a bug in your script or module.

Less likely, you are using that application for a purpose that it was not designed for (if so, stop).

Comment: it is a code for calculations but the file is too big and stops before it is finished.. is there any solution as I need this calculations.

Comment: can i use cuda of laptop for solving this as I have a laptop with RTX 2060 Ram 16 Gb

Comment: anon-rss is about memory, the application name is Python (see "Killed process **24502 (python)**").

Comment: excuse me I didn't get what do you mean. i know its a python code that caused this problem while running the code .. i need to handle this problem